# Is there any way to use an object across two STA threads in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, object, telerik

Okay, before anyone starts up, let me be clear...

I'm using a custom control, in this case Telerik's RadPane. When you deserialize these panes they come in through a callback method, and thus, are ALL owned/deserialized by one thread, and they cannot be cloned or deep copied, etc. so there are some huge limitations I am trying to work with. This is bad because, I want to add content to each pane but want them all to work within the confines of their own UI thread. For example, I want to add a list to a pane and have it update with millions of records, etc. but if I update one pane, the UI thread will lock up for all panes.

I need to create the contents of this object in a different thread, but the problem is, when I try to set the content, the obvious issue is that the object is not owned by the same thread that owns my pane:

```
myRadPane.Content = myGrid;
```

myGrid is owned by a different thread than myRadPane, so it doesn't want to set the content. Is there any way around this problem in WPF or a way to allow one object to be "shared" across UI threads?

Edit: Please note, I am fully aware of how dispatchers work, and my application makes use of them whenever the main UI thread needs updating for one pane. However, in this case, even while using dispatchers as minimally as possible, the UI thread bogs down under heavy load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN copy WPF controls.

Call this in your creater Thread:

```
    public string CopyWPFControl<T>(T source)
    {
        string childXaml = XamlWriter.Save(source);
        var stringReader = new StringReader(childXaml);
        return stringReader.ToString();
    }
```

Transfer your result to your Dispatcher / STA thread and call:

```
    public T RecreateWPFControl<T>(string source)
    {
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(source);
        var clonedChild = (T)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
        return clonedChild;
    }
```

So create your object in a Diferent Thread, then copy the Control and all its Bindings ect and use the output to display.

imported this will only copy the XAML description.

Comment: Just a note, I went with saving the child's XAML string in the original thread that owns the object, and then passed just the XAML string into a call to the copy method, which I did in the new thread that I want to own it in order to copy it.

Comment: But wait, even though I can copy it locally, it seems I still have a big problem...now it seems I need to pass the local copy back to the main thread in order to show it in this RadDocking control. It just occurred to me that to add panes you have to call the following method on the main UI thread's pane group (since the UI thread owns the pane group): myRadPaneGroup.AddItem(myPane, Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking.DockPosition.Center); ...which won't work now :(

Comment: i do not understand the problem now ... you want to create a Control and set Property in that. Than you want to Copy the control with all propertys and create a new one in your Dispatcher Thread. I don't know why this should be a s big performance problem? Even if you are realy working with millions of data you do not need to create a control by your self for each item. Inform yourself about [Data Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). if you simply create a new Control for each item you are ignore nearly every aspect of WPF ;-)

Comment: PS: the real creation ... like `new Control()` needs to be done in the Dispacher there is absolute NO workaround for that. you could just define the propertys and then copy the control.

Comment: Yeah, seems like I need to find other reasons for performance hits I'm seeing because there's no real way to get around this.

Comment: I would recommand to define a DataTemplate for your Model. Then display your UI elements. THEN gray the surface and display a Wait screen while you loading your data in background and than simply push the data in a any List provider control that is designed for that purpose.

I hope you find your solution :-)

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't really explain how these controls work. This is where you are having problems understanding my issue: RadPanes act like a Window. You add content to a RadPane, like RadPane.Content = new Grid(); The problem is that, I can't create a new STA UI thread for that RadPane like I would normally be able to do for a Window, because to display it, I need to add it to a RadPaneGroup which is in another thread...and when you save the layout and load it back in, it comes in and out of that thread too, with no way around it. Its a limitation on the control, itself.

Comment: Maybe you do not understand the Purpose of the Dispatcher. The dispatcher Should be the only one who interacts and workes with UI controls. If you want to create a new one you need the Create a new Thread and set the [ApartmentState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.apartmentstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But then, the controls! are sepperated and bound to the Creator thread. This is no problem since we are able to Sepperate UI and Data. The create of your UI should NEVER take that much time that you are thinking about a creation in an other thread. -> see next post

Comment: next post -> why should the creation of `new Grid();` take that much time? If you need to add your control to a group like the `RadPaneGroup` you simple not able to create it in a new Thread or your simply create a new RadPaneGroup. Why do you realy need to create a new Thread ( wich cause in a new creation of a new dispatcher ). Again if the Creation of your control take that time do not use it! if your performance problems caused by a huge creation of grids, use a Control that is designed for that.

Comment: No, I get dispatchers fully. When you deal with millions of records that are databound to a pane's lists, and are showing them all at the same time, things can get very loaded, especially when you have asynchronous messages come in that you need to update the list with, and notify of changes to the data binding. So if all your lists are in ONE THREAD, then YES, you CAN, even with MINIMAL DISPATCHING, have ISSUES with UI BLOCKING. I'm not JUST adding a GRID to the UI, OBVIOUSLY.

Comment: YOU HAVE TO ALWAYS DISPATCH TO THE CREATOR THREAD TO UPDATE THAT CONTROL'S DATABOUND ELEMENTS. That could...require data template updates, ETC...which CAN TAKE TIME TO UPDATE when you have a huge server solution with millions and millions of messages coming in on multiple lists that are all created on the same creator thread that require you to update a list view in the user interface.

Comment: Why do I really need to create a new UI thread for each pane? That WOULD BE IDEAL in making my UI NON-BLOCKING. Then, I can create elements in that new UI thread, have that new UI thread run its own dispatcher, and dispatch to that UI thread ONLY, INSTEAD OF DISPATCHING TO THE SAME UI THREAD FOR EACH PANE!

Comment: No it would NOT! you still ignore WPFs features for Data bound processing. If you use a Proper control ( like the normal WPF DataTable ) you create the table. THEN you create the data and assign it to the table via Items Source. Every other way will leed to your performance issues. If you follow this simple way you can deal with millions of data rows ect.

Comment: Oh yeah? Why don't you try looping in a while (true) loop off of ten threads into the databound elements of a listview then? Let me know how that goes. Let me know if your UI still responds while constantly having to refresh that data...

Comment: First: `while (true)` is one of the most worst thinks you can do, there is a more secure and more elegant way how you deal with collections or else.
Sec: Why 10 threads that are contently refreshing data? For luck i am working on a similar project currently, that has ( for now ) not that huge amount of data, but also the problem of life shaping data.My system is designed to show data in a WPF DataTable and than update only single entiys on demand. This works with only two threads and is absolute performant. Just to say ... separate UI creation and Data creation.